# How to evenly model and distribute notches around a cylinder?

Tags: modeling

Luke's lightsaber first seemed like an easy one to me but going further down at the grip, it's getting a little difficult.

[image]

Moving the face along its normal's z axis somehow gives me the look but it isn't great. Furthermore, I would need to carefully adjust the upper and lower edges and repeat it all over the handle.

[image]

This seems very challenging to me and I believe, there's a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could create this topology (mirrored on X and Z):

[image]

Give it an *Array* modifier, then a *Simpled Deform* (*Bend* mode, 360° on Z), a *Weld* and a *Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

Comment: that's very clever, just doing it the other way around